# Aurelia - ValidationController always returns true

Tags: aurelia

I've made a wizard with aurelia and I want to check the input values when the user hits the `next` button.

```
@autoinject()
export class settingsWizard {
steps: Step[];
activeStep: Step;
valController: ValidationController;

constructor(private i18n: I18N, private http: HttpClient, public wizard: Wizard, private log: Logger, private router: Router, private controllerFactory: ValidationControllerFactory) {
    this.steps = [
        new Step(1, this.i18n.tr("route1"), PLATFORM.moduleName('./steps/step1')),
        new Step(2, this.i18n.tr("route2"), PLATFORM.moduleName('./steps/step2')),
        new Step(3, this.i18n.tr("route3"), PLATFORM.moduleName('./steps/step3')),
        new Step(4, this.i18n.tr("route4"), PLATFORM.moduleName('./steps/step4')),
    ];

    ValidationRules
        .ensure('availableTotalTime').required().on(this.wizard.plannedTime);
        //.ensureObject()
        //.satisfies((x: IQualityRate) => x.numberOfProducedQuantity > x.rejects)
        //.withMessage(this.i18n.tr('quality-rate.rejectsHigherThanProducedQuantity'))
        //.on(wizard.qualityRate);

    this.valController = controllerFactory.createForCurrentScope();
    this.valController.validateTrigger = validateTrigger.manual;
}
```

here's the nextButton event:

```
   nextStep() {
    this.valController.validate().then(result => {
        if (result.valid) {
            if (this.activeStep.id !== this.steps.length) {
                this.activeStep = this.steps[this.activeStep.id];
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My aurelia ValidationController always returns `result.valid = true` even though `availableTotalTime` is `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be assuming that the `ValidationRules` api automatically causes objects to be validated, but it only stores the rules on the object's prototype.

The `ValidationController` only validates objects which are either explicitly (1) or implicitly (2) registered, or directly provided (3) to it.

#### 1. Register "implicitly"

Any property in a view that has the `& validate` binding behavior on it will be validated whenever you call `controller.validate()` in the same viewmodel.

#### 2. Register explicitly

Likewise, `controller.addObject(this.wizard.plannedTime)` will cause that object (and all its properties) to be validated on subsequent calls to `.validate()`

#### 3. Provide a `ValidateInstruction`

```
this.valController.validate({
    object: this.wizard.plannedTime,
    // optional: propertyName: ...,
    // optional: rules: ...
});
```

This gives you the highest degree of control. It will *only* validate the object you pass in, and nothing else. Also it won't register the object, so subsequent calls to `.validate()` will not automatically validate it again.

You'll probably either want to go with option 2 or 3, depending on other concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up here as I was getting the same problem. Fred Kleuver's answer is correct, but only when using `.on` to register your view model (or in this case, the object with the property to be validated) when creating your rules.

If you are like me and you're explicitly passing in the validation rules into the binding behavior, like `& validate:myRules` (this happens to be how most of the examples I've seen online doing it) you will need to follow the [Entity Validation](https://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/validation#entity-validation) portion of the documentation.That way you can explicitly pass your validation rules into your `validationController.addObject` call in the same way you would pass your rules to your binding behavior in your view.

```
this.validationRules = ValidationRules
    .ensure('availableTotalTime')
    .required()
    .rules;

this.validationController.addObject(this.wizard.plannedTime, this.validationRules);
```